# Python inconsistencies issues- Adafruit io

Tags: python, python-3.x, adafruit, adafruit-circuitpython

So i have a simple block of code:

```
# Import library and create instance of REST client.
from Adafruit_IO import Client, Feed
aio = Client('aio_bleepbloop')

# Get list of feeds.
feeds = aio.feeds()

# Print out the feed names:
for f in feeds:
    print('Feed: {0}'.format(f.name))

dataRoll = aio.receive('diceRoll').value
dataType = aio.receive('diceType').value
print(dataRoll, dataType)
```

On one PC running python 3.7.4 works jsut fine and runs- On my home PC running 3.8.5 i get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-41fb818ed5ba> in <module>
      1 # Import library and create instance of REST client.
      2 from Adafruit_IO import Client, Feed
----> 3 aio = Client('aio_bleepbloop')
      4 
      5 # Get list of feeds.

TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'key'
```

And i hoenstly dont know why.

Comment: Which version of the package is each interpreter running? Quite possible this is due to a difference in package version

Comment: There's been some volatility in that constructor over time, you can see two signatures for it between these two versions, for example: https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_IO_Python/blob/api-v1/Adafruit_IO/client.py#L44 and the current one https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_IO_Python/blob/37663ab3ed5219027274527de2c998ca517ec7e5/Adafruit_IO/client.py#L46

Answer (score 0):

you could try

```
aio = Client("username", "aio_bloopbloop")
```